# How can I create a trigger that takes most recently updated record in one table, and appends it to the matching record in another upon approval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have two tables in MS SQL Server:

- INFO
- STAGE_INFO

The STAGE_INFO is a copy of the INFO table, but only contains entries for information updates that users submit for review through a web app.

I.E. User would submit a change for an attribute in the INFO table ( info_key=2).
Stage_info creates a row with the updated information (ex, a new name), that corresponds with info_key=2. The INFO_STATUS would be READY_FOR_REVIEW upon the user submitting the change. Once the status is changed to approved, I would like to append the new information to the existing info_key=2 in the INFO Table. This isn't the part i'm struggling with, as much as what happens once there have been multiple entries in the STAGE_INFO table for info_key=2. I want to take the one with the most recent update_date.

Is the best way to do this by creating a trigger? And if so, how do I trigger it to only take the most recently updated record for that key.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you would be able to provide an answer based only on the information written. I can't begin to understand what you are asking here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would be a great place to start.

Comment: How is the status going to get changed to approved?

Answer (score 1):

No, a trigger is not the right tool for this.   Whatever process you use to change the status to approved should also include the code to UPDATE the `INFO` table, and should include logic to select the most recent record for the key of the approved update.